# Компиляция массива в GAS

Tags: c, ассемблер, gcc

Что означают закомментированные строки?

GAS code

```
.text
.globl  main
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
;   subq    $48, %rsp
;   movq    %fs:40, %rax
;   movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
;   xorl    %eax, %eax
    movl    $1, -48(%rbp)
    movl    $2, -44(%rbp)
    movl    $3, -40(%rbp)
    movl    $4, -36(%rbp)
    movl    $5, -32(%rbp)
    movl    $6, -28(%rbp)
    movl    $7, -24(%rbp)
    movl    $8, -20(%rbp)
    movl    $9, -16(%rbp)
;   movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
;   xorq    %fs:40, %rax
    leave
    ret
```

С code

```
void main() {
    int array[9];
    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 2;
    array[2] = 3;
    array[3] = 4;
    array[4] = 5;
    array[5] = 6;
    array[6] = 7;
    array[7] = 8;
    array[8] = 9;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это [защита от переполнения буфера](https://wiki.osdev.org/Stack_Smashing_Protector)

```
subq    $48, %rsp      ; Выделение стека
movq    %fs:40, %rax   ; Получение значения "канарейки"
movq    %rax, -8(%rbp) ; Сохранение его
xorl    %eax, %eax     ; Обнуление регистра

...

movq    -8(%rbp), %rax ; Загрузка значения "канарейки"
xorq    %fs:40, %rax   ; Проверка на соответствие оригинальному значению
```